# What is the difference between (pointer + n) and pointer[n]?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, pointer-arithmetic

In this code, I don't understand why the input character value is being put into (ptr + i) but then we print out ptr[i]. I know they are different because I am printing out the values in the first for loop, but I don't understand what the difference between them is and why we are using one to accept input with scanf and a different one to output.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main ()
{
    int n, i;
    char *ptr;
    printf ("Enter number of characters to store: ");
    scanf ("%d", &n);

    ptr = (char *) malloc (n * sizeof (char));
    printf("POINTER %p\n", ptr);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf ("Enter ptr[%d] (%p) (%p): ", i, ptr[i], ptr + i);
        /* notice the space preceding %c is
            necessary to read all whitespace in the input buffer
        */
        scanf (" %c", ptr + i);
    }

    printf ("\nPrinting elements of 1-D array: \n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf ("%c ", ptr[i]);
    }

    //signal to operating system program ran fine
    return 0;
}
```

In addition, I know doing ptr + i = ptr + (i * numberofbytes) based on the number of bytes of the data type of pointer, so it makes sense that we would store each new input into a memory address with that number of bytes that we used malloc for. But then why do we print out ptr[i] instead of ptr + i?

Hope this is described specifically enough, let me know if it isn't.

Thank you!

Comment: `(ptr + i)` is the same address as `&ptr[i]` whereas `ptr[i]` is its value, also `*(ptr + i)`. So `scanf (" %c", ptr + i);` is identical to `scanf (" %c", &ptr[i]);`

Comment: `(pointer + n)` is `&pointer[n]` or `&n[pointer]` and `pointer[n]` is `*(pointer + n)` or `[pointer]n` - these are the only differences.

Comment: `a[i]` is just syntactic sugar for `*(a+i)`.  This implies that the `[]` operator is commutative, which it is.  So `a[i]` and `i[a]` are equivalent, although by convention you should put the pointer on the left and the offset on the right.

Comment: Thank you so much that makes a lot of sense. I really appreciate it!

Comment: And my favorite: 1["hello"] == 'e'.

Answer (score 3):

Due to the pointer arithmetic the expression `ptr + i` has the type `char *` and points to the i-th elemenet of the array. The function `scanf` expects a pointer to an object to which  the entered data will be stored.

The expression `ptr[i]` that is the same as `*( ptr + i )` yields the object pointed to by the expression `ptr + i`.

From  the C Standard (6.5.2.1 Array subscripting)

> 2 A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets []
> is a subscripted designation of an element of an array object. The
> definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to
> (*((E1)+(E2))). Because of the conversion rules that apply to the
> binary + operator, if E1 is an array object (equivalently, a pointer
> to the initial element of an array object) and E2 is an integer,
> E1[E2] designates the E2-th element of E1 (counting from zero).

So the expression  `ptr + i`  points to the i-th object. And the expression `*( ptr + i )` that is the same as `ptr[i]` yields the object itself pointed to by the expression `ptr + i`.

Answer (score 1):

`ptr[i]` is equivalent to `*(ptr + i)`, by definition.

This means that

`&ptr[i]` is equivalent to `&*( ptr + i )` and thus to `ptr + i`.

As such, the difference is that the code passes the value of `ptr[i]` to `printf`, but the address of `ptr[i]` to `scanf`.

We need to pass a pointer to `scanf` because having the value of `ptr[i]` does not allow it to write to `ptr[i]`. Only passing the address of `ptr[i]` does that. But `printf` simply needs the value to format and print. It doesn't care from where the value came.

```c
// Passes a pointer to `ptr[i]` to `scanf`.
// `scanf` will write at the address pointed by this pointer.
scanf( " %c", ptr + i );

// Same
scanf( " %c", &ptr[i] );

// Passes the value of `ptr[i]`.
// `printf` will print a formatting of that value.
printf( "%c ", ptr[i] );
```

Answer (score 0):

The value at the address of (ptr+i) or simply *(ptr+i) is the same as ptr[i]. You have mentioned that you know ptr+i denotes the memory location as (i*no.of bytes of the pointer's data type). I think it is notable to mention that **an array is also a pointer pointing towards the Zeroth index of array**. Another main thing is that although both as a pointer and array they are the same, you cannot reinitialise  an array once it is initialised as ***int array[size]*** , but you can always reinitialise an array if it was initialised as array: ****int* *array***

Thus  I would say both are same and you should use them according to your problem and convenience.
I hope this helped.